# PostgreSQL fdw and view, working with timestamp

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I have a PostgreSQL 9.6 server connecting to remote 9.3 server.

I'm trying to create the following materialized view :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test AS
  SELECT id
  FROM remote.logs
  WHERE remote.logs.created_at > (now() - interval '1 day')
```

It's slow because the filtering is done on local server.

Here is the EXPLAIN ANALYSE result :

```
Foreign Scan on integration.logs  (cost=100.00..219.69 rows=975 width=4)
  Output: id
  Filter: (logs.created_at > (now() - '1 day'::interval))
  Remote SQL: SELECT id, created_at FROM public.logs
```

How to make condition filtering on the remote server ?

Note : remote filtering is working with such a query :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test AS
  SELECT id
  FROM integration.logs
  WHERE integration.logs.created_at > (timestamp 'now()' - interval'1 day')

Foreign Scan on integration.logs  (cost=100.00..166.06 rows=975 width=4)
  Output: id
  Remote SQL: SELECT id FROM public.logs WHERE ((created_at > '2017-05-31 11:44:10.89017'::timestamp without time zone))
```

But with this, each time I refreh the view, the date has already been calculated and stay for example above at 2017-05-31 11:44:10.89017

Any ideas ?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

> To reduce the risk of misexecution of queries, WHERE clauses are not
>   sent to the remote server unless they use only data types, operators,
>   and functions that are built-in or belong to an extension that's
>   listed in the foreign server's extensions option. Operators and
>   functions in such clauses must be IMMUTABLE as well.

Function `now()` is not immutable - it does not give the same result if parameters don't change.

If you really need to send query with now() executed on remote server, then you can use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-function.html) for that.

Comment: Nice ! Thanks you ! Works like a charm, even if fdw is more simple and secure